# Problem with pageFetcher

Tags: java, compiler-errors

for(int i = 0; i < citylink.length; i++) {
        body=pF.fetchpage(citylink[i][1]);
        // It's for taking the url from the table citylink
        // and returns the source of this url!

I have also declared it in my `pagefetcher.java` class like this:

```
public String fetchPage(String url) {
    try {
        url = URIUtil.encodeQuery(url);
    } catch (URIException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but when I compile it it says that the method `fetchpage(String)` is undefined for the type `PageFetcher` and I can't run my problem! I don't know what to do.

Comment: Please format source code using the "code sample" button on the editor, it makes things far easier to read.

Comment: Replace the second line of code with `body=pF.fetchPage(citylink[i][1]);`, that should solve he actual problem

Answer (score 0):

Your method needs to return a string. The method is declared as a public String, but fails to return the value you want (url)

Comment: public String fetchPage(String citylink) {
        try {
         citylink = URIUtil.encodeQuery(citylink);
        } catch (URIException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        GetMethod get;
        get = new GetMethod(citylink);
        get.setFollowRedirects(true);
i changed my fetchpage.java like this but it still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

You declare your code as

```
public String fetchPage(String url) {
```

And call it as

```
body=pF.fetchpage(citylink[i][1]);
```

Java is **case sensitive**: you should rename either of them to match eachother.

Comment: `pF.fetchPage` or `public String fetchpage`: one of them.

Comment: this excact code worked for another project i don't think that this is the problem and i declare a new instance of pagefetcher PageFetcher pF = new PageFetcher(); so i think that what's in the fetchpage is wrong as a declaration!but i don't know how t fix it